# Равномерно разбить лист на количество строк двумерного массива

Tags: java, массивы, list, коллекции

Пишу метод, который должен равномерно разбить лист на количество строк двумерного массива. Какое условие должно быть для `break`, чтобы массив вывел все значения?

```java
public class ConvertList2Array {
  public int[][] toArray(List<Integer> list, int rows) {
    int cells = list.size() / rows == 0 ? list.size() / rows : (list.size() / rows) + 1;
    int[][] array = new int[rows][cells];
    int row = 0;
    int colum = 0;
    for (int i : list) {
      array[row][colum++] = i;
      if (i == rows) {
        colum = 0;
        row++;
      } else if (??) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Нет необходимости выходить из цикла по условию. Итератор

```
for (int i : list) {}
```

сам переберет весь лист и прекратит работу. Вам достаточно задать массив необходимого размера, который не кончиться раньше, чем все значения из списка попадут туда. Прочитайте код внимательно.

В этом условном операторе

```
if (i == rows) {}
```

вы сравниваете значение полученное из списка с количеством строк `rows`. Зачем? До этого вы инкременируете переменную `colum++`, максимальное значение которой храниться в переменной `cells`. Сделайте проверку корректной.

Чтобы корректно определить размер массива вам надо узнать делиться ли размер списка на количество строк без остатка.

```
int cells = list.size() / rows == 0 ? list.size() / rows : (list.size() / rows) + 1;
```

Оператор получения остатка от деления выглядит как `%`. Измените выражение так чтобы оно давало нужный результат.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что здесь не нужен break вообще. Данный цикл (foreach) сам завершится, когда переберёт все элементы в переданном листе. Если Вы правильно рассчитаете размерность создаваемого массива, то и проблем при вставке в него всех элементов не будет.
С другой стороны, меня настораживает, что в условии сравнивается значение, хранящееся в листе с количеством строк. Точно ли это ожидаемое поведение? Мне кажется, в этом месте вместо i==rows должно быть что-то вроде (colum == cells)

Comment: да и почему бы не сделать так?
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      array[i/rows][i%rows] = list.get(i);
}

Comment: Спасибо, сделал colum == cells все получилось, еще такой вопрос я учусь еще и чувствую что плаваю в массивах, что можете порекомендовать?

Comment: "С другой стороны, меня настораживает, что в условии сравнивается значение, хранящееся в листе с количеством строк. Точно ли это ожидаемое поведение?" если вас не затруднит, можете описать подробней, что это означает?т.е. как вы это видите?

Comment: Можно и подробнее. Скорее всего Вы перепутали i из for (int i=0;i<10;i++) и i из for(int i:list). В первом случае это счётчик, во втором - само значение, хранящееся в листе list. Сравнение значения из списка с количеством строк показалось мне странным.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
int rows = 3;
int columns = list.size() / rows + (list.size() % rows == 0 ? 0 : 1);
int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
int row = 0;
int colum = 0;
for (int element : list) {
    array[row][colum++] = element;
    if (colum == columns) {
        colum = 0;
        row++;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
// [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 0, 0]]
```